# R how can I get only ways from Overpass API and reduce the amount of data

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf, overpass-api

Im trying to reduce the amount of data and time a query to overpass server takes.
Im only interested in ways and by using osmdata Package this is my current approach:

```
library(osmdata)

bbox_dimensions <-c(xmin=11.2360151977671, ymin= 47.8047832575026, xmax= 11.8886729361838, ymax=48.2426118570748)

my_osm_data <- opq(bbox = bbox_dimensions,timeout = 180,memsize = 104857600) %>%
    add_osm_feature(
      key = 'highway', 
     value = c("primary","secondary", "tertiary")
      
    ) %>% 
  osmdata_sf(quiet = FALSE)
```

Is it possible to reduce the amount of data of this query?
Im only interested in way not nodes along the way.

Comment: You are aware of the fact that ways consist of nodes? Without nodes you will loose the way geometry, only tags will remain.

Comment: That is true. I was thinking I need to remove all the nodes like crossings,road signs..

Comment: I don't think you can. There is a nodes_only optional parameter in opq(), but I am not aware of a corresponding ways_only setting. You are likely to have to download everything, and clean up locally.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude features like crossings for example with osmdata?

Comment: You can strip these tags afterwards if you like. Or better keep only the tags you are interested in.

Comment: But that would still require large amount of data to be transfered (what im trying to avoid) if i have to filter locally

Comment: Hello again @Andreas! I think that if you need to query the same `bbox` of OSM lines, then the easiest approach is to save the result returned by osmdata as a `.gpkg` object (check `?sf::st_write`). On the other hand, if you need to work with several different bboxes in a bigger area (i.e. Munchen), then I think you may want to test a package that I'm developing named [`osmextract`](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmextract/). If that's the case, I will add a more detailed answer later today.

Comment: Hi @agila! That sounds awesome. My usecase is to download frequently relativley big parts of OSM data. I try to minimize the amount of time the procedure takes to agregate the data on osm server and to download it. One of approaches i also try is to create polygon bbox with excluding areas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66868435/r-remove-overlapping-area-of-bounding-boxes  Im absolutely interrested in osmextract!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, I would suggest the following approach if you need to run several queries for OSM data that belong to the same geographical area.

First of all, load packages

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(osmextract)
#> Data (c) OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright.
#> Check the package website, https://docs.ropensci.org/osmextract/, for more details.
library(tmap)
tmap_mode("view")
#> tmap mode set to interactive viewing
```

Define the `bbox` and convert to `sfc` object (see the discussion on [github](https://github.com/ropensci/osmextract/issues/185#issuecomment-810336602)):

```r
my_bbox <- st_bbox(
  c(xmin = 11.2360151977671, ymin = 47.8047832575026, xmax = 11.8886729361838, ymax = 48.2426118570748), 
  crs = 4326
)
my_bbox_poly <- st_as_sfc(my_bbox)
```

Then we need to download OSM extract for a particular geographical area that should cover all your queries. If you are working with data in Germany, then I would suggest checking the `geofabrik` and `bbbike` providers:

```
oe_match(my_bbox_poly, provider = "geofabrik")
#> The input place was matched with multiple geographical areas.
#> Selecting the smallest administrative unit. Check ?oe_match for more details.
#> $url
#> [1] "https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/germany/bayern/oberbayern-latest.osm.pbf"
#> 
#> $file_size
#> [1] 185338670
oe_match(my_bbox_poly, provider = "bbbike")
#> $url
#> [1] "https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Muenchen/Muenchen.osm.pbf"
#> 
#> $file_size
#> [1] 58400897
```

The extract returned by the `bbbike` provider is much smaller than the extract returned by `geofabrik`; hence I will run the following steps using the OSM data returned by `bbbike`.

```r
oe_get("Muenchen", provider = "bbbike", download_only = TRUE, skip_vectortranslate = TRUE)
#> The input place was matched with: Muenchen
#> File downloaded!
#> [1] "C:\\Users\\Utente\\Documents\\osm-data\\bbbike_Muenchen.osm.pbf"
```

Then, if you want to read-in the lines data that belong to a particular bbox and with certain characteristics, then I would suggest the following approach:

```
lines_v1 <- oe_get(
  place = "Muenchen", # or place = my_bbox_poly
  layer = "lines", 
  provider = "bbbike", 
  query = "SELECT * FROM lines WHERE highway IN ('primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary')", 
  wkt_filter = st_as_text(my_bbox_poly) 
)
#> The input place was matched with: Muenchen
#> The chosen file was already detected in the download directory. Skip downloading.
#> Start with the vectortranslate operations on the input file!
#> 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
#> Finished the vectortranslate operations on the input file!
#> Reading layer `lines' from data source `C:\Users\Utente\Documents\osm-data\bbbike_Muenchen.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
#> Simple feature collection with 13032 features and 9 fields
#> Geometry type: LINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 11.19608 ymin: 47.80002 xmax: 11.89542 ymax: 48.25359
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

Please note that the function recognises that you have already downloaded the OSM extract and skips downloading the same file again. This process can be optimised if you set a persistent download directory. See [here](https://github.com/ropensci/osmextract#persistent-download-directory) for more details.

```r
# Check result
tm_shape(my_bbox_poly) + 
  tm_borders(col = "darkred") + 
tm_shape(lines_v1) + 
  tm_lines(lwd = 2)
```

[image]

A more efficient (but much more tricky) approach is the following:

```r
lines_v2 <- oe_get(
  place = "Muenches", 
  layer = "lines", 
  provider = "bbbike", 
  vectortranslate_options = c(
    "-f", "GPKG", 
    "-overwrite", 
    "-where", "highway IN ('primary', 'secondary', 'tertiary')", 
    "-clipsrc", st_as_text(my_bbox_poly), 
    "-nlt", "PROMOTE_TO_MULTI",
    "lines"
  )
)
#> The input place was matched with: Muenchen
#> The chosen file was already detected in the download directory. Skip downloading.
#> Start with the vectortranslate operations on the input file!
#> 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
#> Finished the vectortranslate operations on the input file!
#> Reading layer `lines' from data source `C:\Users\Utente\Documents\osm-data\bbbike_Muenchen.gpkg' using driver `GPKG'
#> Simple feature collection with 13027 features and 9 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 11.23602 ymin: 47.80478 xmax: 11.88867 ymax: 48.24261
#> Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
```

Graphical check

```r
# Check result
tm_shape(my_bbox_poly) + 
  tm_borders(col = "darkred") + 
tm_shape(lines_v2) + 
  tm_lines(lwd = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Summary:

1. If you need to import OSM data several times, then you should a [persistent download directory](https://github.com/ropensci/osmextract#persistent-download-directory). That also implies that you don't need to download an OSM extract every time you run a new query (unless the requested data are not included in any of the existing extracts).
2. If you need to import OSM lines covering a medium/small geographical region, I would suggest adopting the "query" approach (i.e. lines_v1).
3. The second approach has several benefits (i.e. it's faster than the other one, especially for larger extracts, and, as you can see from the previous plot, it clips the lines instead of selecting the roads that intersect the box). On the other hand, it's quite difficult to write the vectortranslate options from scratch (we are working on a more intuitive API but it's just under development for the moment). Moreover, that option modifies the underlying structure of the `.gpkg` file (which may have [relevant consequences](https://github.com/ropensci/osmextract/issues/181)). We are working on a solution for both problems, but you need to wait until version 0.3 or 0.4.

Check [here](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmextract/), [here](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmextract/articles/providers_comparisons.html), and [here](https://docs.ropensci.org/osmextract/articles/osmextract.html) for more details behind osmextract.

Feel free to add here any question or comment.

Comment: Hi @agila, 
the methods you propose work very well, but extract a lot of distinct nodes, whereas sometimes, there is ways that should really be one large line, instead of multiple small lines. Is there any way to extract these as ONE linestring? e.g. long highways or railways... Thanks!

Comment: Hi! I think that there is no general solution, but you can extract connected ways as long as they belong to the same [route](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:route). For example: https://gist.github.com/agila5/ab2445e0cb5d148accb8e423dc63d2b1

Comment: Hi agila,
thank you very much for preparing this nice example. I have used it on my region of interest and have realized, that not all routes that should be routes are classified as such. I am actually trying to construct a road network graph object, but this goes beyond this question for sure. I will try to write a decently written question some time. Thanks for now!